# JSON String in android how to get the values

Tags: android, json

I have this JSON string in my android app

```
[{"tel1":"999","tel2":"0790000000","tel3":"","interval":"60","deleteLocal":"1","id":"2"}]
```

How do I parse this into a JsonArray and then get the values, for example, tel1?

Comment: If you're trying to do it with PHP, use `json_decode()` (with the second parameter set to `TRUE`): http://php.net/json_decode

Comment: @AmalMurali, OP wants to traverse the JSON generated from PHP into his Android App.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran: Ah, I see. I wasn't sure about that - which is why added "If you're trying to do it with PHP" at the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
try
    {
       JSONArray jArray= new JSONArray(output);
       JSONObject jsonObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
       String tel= jsonObject.getString("tel1");
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
     //error parsing response.
    }
```

Comment: if jArray having no data means length = 0 then what happen at line `JSONObject jsonObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);`

Comment: you can check just before 2nd line if(jArray.length()) then continue parsing.

Answer (score 1):

Do like This

**{**- represents JsonObject

**[**- represents JsonArray

```
  try
        {
        JSONArray jArray= new JSONArray(output);
               JSONObject menuObject = JSONArray.getJSONObject(0);  
               String tel= menuObject.getString("tel1");
        }catch(Exception e)
        {

Log.e("d",e.getMessage());
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```
try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(responsestring);
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject jobj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String strtel1 = jobj.getString("tel1");

            Log.i("value tel1 : ", strtel1 + "");
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
```

Comment: I get this error Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getJSONObject(int) from the type JSONArray

Comment: sorry i made a mistake now check my answer ...use this `JSONObject jobj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);`

Comment: @TomS : Heyy in your accepted answer if jArray having no data means length = 0 then what happen at line `JSONObject jsonObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);` ???

Answer (score 1):

Try This.

```
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(result);
JSONObject jObj = arr.getJSONObject(0);
String tel1 = jObj.getString("tell");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
try {
    JSONArray jsonArray= new JSONArray(yourString);
    if(jsonArray != null && jsonArray.length() > 0) {
        for(int i=0; i< jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            if(json != null) {
                String tel1 = json.optString("tel1", "default_value");
                Log.d("PARSE", "tel1  : "+tel1);
            }
        }
    }
}catch(Exception e)
{
}
```